# Прозрачность окна

Tags: wpf, .net, xaml, прозрачность

Могу ли я при таких настройках Window

```
AllowsTransparency="True"
<Window.Background>
    <SolidColorBrush Opacity="0.30" Color="Black"/>
</Window.Background>
```

Осветлить какую то часть до `Opacity="0.01"?`

Т.е. есть `Window`, на нём `Canvas`, на `Canvas` есть `Rectangle` и там где находится`Rectangle`, я хочу осветлить.

Или это как то делается иначе ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сделать часть окна еще более прозрачной нельзя, т.к. слои накладываются друг на друга. Придется действовать наоборот — делать окно с максимальной прозрачностью, а фигуры на нем с меньшей прозрачностью:

```
<Window ...
        AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent" WindowStyle="None">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid Background="Black" Opacity="0.3" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
        <Grid Background="Black" Opacity="0.3" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Grid Background="Black" Opacity="0.3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"/>
        <Grid Background="Black" Opacity="0.3" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="2"/>

        <Grid Background="Black" Opacity="0.01" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Управляя шириной столбцов и высотой строк корневого `Grid` — управляете размерами и положением прозрачного отверстия в окне.

Если вам подойдет полностью прозрачная внутренняя область — этого же эффекта можно добиться с помощью `CombinedGeometry` в режиме `Exclude`, будет выглядеть немного проще:

```
<Window ...
        AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent" WindowStyle="None">

    <Path Fill="Black" Opacity="0.3">
        <Path.Data>
            <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Exclude">
                <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                    <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,1000,1000"/>
                </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                    <RectangleGeometry Rect="70,30,150,100"/>
                </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
            </CombinedGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
</Window>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можете придумать и другое решение, основанное на этом принципе: окно максимально прозрачное, элементы на нем с нужным цветом и прозрачностью.